# Limit the range of a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to trigger a click event on my *input fields* whenever the user clicks on the *fieldsets* containing them, so even if they don't click exactly on the *input*. Here's what it looks like :

```
<fieldset>
    <input name="age" placeholder="Age">
</fieldset>
```

And here's my JS:

```
$('fieldset').on('click', function(){
//  $(this).find('input').click();
    $(this).find('input').focus();
})
```

I first tried to trigger a click, but this would generate an "infinite loop" since every click would trigger another click. This issue is solved with *focus()*, but the problem is that doesn't trigger the [Jquery autocompletion plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) which I'm using. Only the click seems to do that. I think that there is a way to limit the "range" of the JS-generated click so that it only impacts the input field and not the whole fieldset. If there is a cleaner way to solve this, feel free to share.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just want to use the .triggerHandler() method (see docs here: https://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) with or without also calling focus, to simulate the click event without also bubbling the event up the tree and recalling the click event on the fieldset.

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){console.log('clicked')})
$('fieldset').on('click', function(){
    debugger
    $(this).find('input').triggerHandler('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <input name="age" placeholder="Age">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Works great ! Thanks.